# What kind a SQL query use rails to retrieve data in console

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, database

When I fire `User.first.email` in Rails - 4 console it gives me query like 
`SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1` 
By this query structure how it can get `email` column from database just only firing `SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"` in rails.
Please provide needful description for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a query equivalent to `SELECT "users".* FROM "users"` you should be using the following in your console:

```
User.all
```

If you want to just select the email field, generating the query `SELECT "users"."email" FROM "users"` you would use the `pluck` modifier, which will return you an array of emails:

```
User.pluck(:email)
```

Notice we've dropped the `all` query modifier. It isn't required in this instance, but you can add it for clarity if you like:

```
User.all.pluck(:email)
```

Be aware though that this will return you an array just containing your requested attribute, not instances of the model they belong to.

For that, you would use the `select` modifier:

```
User.select(:email)
#or
User.all.select(:email)
```

This will return you instances of your `User` class with `email` populated with the data from the DB. This is useful if you need to chain this query with others, but will be less performant than the `pluck` alternative with a large dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@users = User.select("email")
```

Comment: thanks...as you suggested this will fire `SELECT "users"."email" FROM "users"` and now i got my answer from your this reference.Thanks again for help.:)